# Nuxt dynamic routes - Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined`

Tags: nuxt.js, contentful

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/20/create-a-blog-with-contentful-and-nuxt/) on building a Contentful-powered blog with Nuxt

I am successful in rendering a list of blog posts, however I am running into an issue with dynamic pages based on the slug of a post.

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/blog/hello-world/` I get the following error:

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined`
```

And yes, I definitely have a blog post with the slug `hello-world`

[image: contentful-blog-post]

I've tried it with other slugs as well, same error.

In `Nuxt.config.js` I've set the following to generate routes

```js
const contentful = require("contentful");
const contentfulClient = contentful.createClient({
 space: 'mySpaceId',
 accessToken: 'myAccessToken'
});

export default {

  ...

  generate: {
   routes() {
     return Promise.all([
       contentfulClient.getEntries({
         content_type: "blogPost"
       })
     ]).then(([blogEntries]) => {
       return [...blogEntries.items.map(entry => entry.fields.slug)];
     });
   }
  },

  ...
```

I've followed the tutorial exactly in configuring `store/index.js`, `plugins/contentful.js`, `plugins/posts.js` and `blog/_slug.vue`

```html
<template>
 <section class="container">

   <h1>{{ post.fields.title }}</h1>
   <p class="author">By {{ post.fields.author.fields.name }}</p>
   <div
     class="image"
     :style="
       `background: url(https:${post.fields.heroImage.fields.file.url}) center center no-repeat`
     "
   ></div>
   <article v-html="$md.render(post.fields.body)"></article>
 </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
       return {
         slug: this.$route.params.slug
       };
     },
     computed: {
       post() {
         let post = this.$store.state.posts.filter(
           el => el.fields.slug === this.slug
         );
         return post[0];
       }
     },
     head() {
       return {
         title: this.post.fields.title
       };
     }
  };
</script>
```

I'm very new to frontend development, and so I am not sure how I could even troubleshoot this. Any tips or guidance are appreciated!

Comment: Do the ``store`` fetches the post correctly?

Comment: @ManiMirjavadi - how do I check this?

Comment: There are different methods for it. If you are fetching it from a server-side backend, you can check it in network tab of developer tools of your browser. You can check if the response is correct and the ``post`` is correctly defined. The other method is using Vue dev tools and check the states in Vuex tab.

Comment: Got it. So, on the `/blog` page - which is working correctly - I do see a GET to `entries?content_type=blogPost` which returns an array of blog entries. However on this page, `/blog/hello-world` I do not see any requests to API